# Clear a pending authorization for certificate (ACME) after rateLimit error

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm using Let's Encrypt for my site, and I had an error in my cron job that resulted in an error when I attempted to manually renew (`$ sudo letsencrypt renew`):

> Error: urn:acme:error:rateLimited :: There were too many requests of
>   a given type :: Error creating new authz :: Too many currently pending
>   authorizations.

My certificate has already expired so I can't wait the 7 days for it to clear.

The [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/) site indicates I can clear one of the pending requests:

> If you have a large number of pending authorization objects and are
>   getting a rate limiting error, you can trigger a validation attempt
>   for those authorization objects by submitting a JWS-signed POST to one
>   of its challenges, as described in the [ACME spec](https://github.com/ietf-wg-acme/acme/blob/master/draft-ietf-acme-acme.md#responding-to-challenges).

I have the logs with the URLs, but I don't understand how to manually send a "JWS-signed POST".

Here's an example of today's that was rejected, from the log:

```
2017-03-31 06:40:32,180:DEBUG:root:Sending POST request to https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-authz. 
args: (), kwargs: {
    'data': '{
        "header": {
            "alg": "RS256",
            "jwk": {"e": "AQAB", "kty": "RSA", "n": "srgrg....huXi0sQ"}
        }, 
        "protected": "rsgrgs....ZJIn0", 
        "payload": "srgrg....In0", 
        "signature": "sgggserg....Tc-Q"
    }'
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Refer these links https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/tool-for-clearing-invalidating-pending-authz/34507 for clearing pending authorizations.https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/tool-for-clearing-pending-authz-looks-at-certbot-log-files-and-uses-acme-library/35436 and https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certbot-too-many-pending-authorisations/35369/4